# Don't know why my sitemap is showing less results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap, sitemap-generator-gem

I'm using sitemap_generator gem, and everything works fine, except that when running my rake task:

```
heroku run rake sitemap:refresh --remote live
```

I get the following results:

```
In '/app/public/':
+ sitemap.xml.gz                                        2409 links /    20.5 KB
Sitemap stats: 2,409 links / 1 sitemaps / 0m04s

Pinging with URL 'http://www.decorissimo.es/sitemap.xml.gz':
  Successful ping of Google
  Successful ping of Bing

Pinging with URL 'http://www.decorissimo.es/sitemap.xml.gz':
  Successful ping of Google
  Successful ping of Bing
```

2409 links. But then I go to

```
mysite.com/sitemap.xml.gz
```

And the sitemap there has only 199 links.

**My sitemap.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sitemap_generator'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.mywebe.com" 

 SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do

   Photo.find_each do |photo|
     add user_photo_path(photo.user_id, photo.id), :lastmod => photo.updated_at
   end

   User.find_each do |user|
     add user_path(user.id), :lastmod => user.updated_at
   end

 end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines # Not needed if you use the rake tasks
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the sitemap.rb file?

Comment: And I assume you've copied the production database to development.

Comment: No, im running the rake task on production directly on heroku so the sitemap.rb runs in productions ddbb

Comment: How many Users and Photos are there in your production db?

Comment: About 500 users and 2000 photos

Comment: Do you have a default scope on users/photos, by chance?

Comment: I think the problem comes when generating the new sitemap, because logs say its introducing 2400 links. After that, only 199 links are on sitemap.

Comment: Must be. I just figured I'd check because I had the same problem when I had a default scope on my model. Sounds like that isn't it. Best of luck hunting down the bug. Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna add your environment variable to the cron job

```
heroku run rake sitemap:refresh RAILS_ENV=production --remote live
```